# How can I halt a check for intersections of sets in python when it discovers one member of the intersection?

Tags: physics, python, intersection

How can I halt a check for intersections of sets in python when it discovers one member of the intersection? I want to do this so that when checking for collisions the moment an intersecting point is discovered, it will immediately halt the check and consider a collision.

Comment: How are you iterating over the sets?